# Is it possible to detect if element exists, then prompt for user input?

Tags: node.js, headless, puppeteer

So I have a use case scenario where I want to check if something exists i.e. a security checkbox. If it does then it prompts the user to put an input. I already have another package that takes in a prompt but not sure how to implement to combine it with this.

```
var result = await new Promise( function (resolve, reject) {
    prompt.get(schema, function (err, result) {
        console.log('Command-line input received:');
        console.log('  password: ' + result.password);
        resolve(result);
        reject("error with prompt")
    })

});
console.log(result);
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false });
const page = await browser.newPage();
await page.goto(url);

try {
    await page.waitFor("#security", { timeout: 3000 });
    // do something if there is a security box
}
catch (e) {
    console.error('no security');
}
```

#### Edit

Can be checked by just using a try catch with a waitFor

```
try {
    await page.waitFor("#login-form-os-captcha", { timeout: 1000 });
    console.log("there is captcha")
}
catch (e) {
    console.error('no captcha');
    // process.exit(1);
}
```

Comment: Look at my edit, i think its what you want

Answer (score 0):

Edited with a promise:

```
//...


// create a promise with the search in the page
searchElement(selector) => new Promise( function (resolve, reject){
  try{
     var elemAwait = await page.$eval(selector, el => el);
     resolve(selector,elemAwait);
  }catch{
     reject(selector,"Element doesn't exist");     
  }
});

// now, search element in the headless page
searchElement('#security')
.then(function(selector,el){
    // element is here
    prompt.get(schema, function (err, result) {

        console.log(selector+' is here with value:' + el.value);

    });
})
.catch(function(selector,msg){
     // element isn't here
    prompt.get(schema, function (err, result) {

        console.log(selector+" - "+msg);


    });
});
```

Relative to:

https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/headless-chrome#cri

https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pageselector

https://github.com/flatiron/prompt

Comment: It gets a failed to find element matching selector. How do I do an "if exist" then prompt?

Comment: Hmm, it seems that if I just do a `await page.waitFor("#login-form-os-captcha", { timeout: 1000 });` in a try catch and just don't do anything in the catch it will work. But now I have an issue where I can't access variables defined outside of the await :\

Comment: What do you means ? (edit your post with that you said)

Comment: can't seem to run your examples, it's giving me `Unexpected identifier` for the `await page.$eval` but thanks anyway, I've got it working.